# SQL: Audit Query to Join/Compare Requirements?

Tags: sql, join, compare

I have 2 sections in a database.  Drafts and Albums.  So we get a draft for an album.  The drafts have requirements, and later an album is created.  That album also has requirements, but the requirements on both sides are entered independently.  Some will change, be dropped, new ones added, etc.  I am trying to make a query to compare those requirements, when an album is assigned as having coming from a specific draft.

The table structure looks like this:

Drafts:ID, draft fields

Draft Requirements: ID, Draft FK, Requirement Type FK

Albums: ID, Drafk FK (not required immediately, but will only be able to audit against a draft, if this is not null), album fields

Album Requirements: ID, Album FK, Requirement Type FK

So I want to create a query with the following:

Draft Fields, Album Fields, Draft Requirements, Album Requirements

Basically if there are 10 requirements it would look like this (excuse the code, wanted to try to make a table, so you can really see):

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Draft Req</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Album Req</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R5</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R7</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R9</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">R9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the first part of the query, with just basic info for the draft and album:

```
SELECT vw_CMP_Contacts.ContactNo, vw_CMP_Contacts.ContactName, vw_CMP_Matches.MatchNo, vw_CMP_Matches.MatchName, 
    tblContactDraft.txtOrganization, tblDraftStatus.txtDraftStatus, tblMAlbumStatus.txtAlbumStatus, tblAlbumType.txtAlbumType
    FROM ((((vw_CMP_Matches 
    INNER JOIN (tblMAlbums INNER JOIN tblContactDraft ON tblMAlbums.FKContactDraft = tblContactDraft.ID) ON vw_CMP_Matches.CM_MID = tblMAlbums.FKMatch) 
    INNER JOIN tblDraftStatus ON tblContactDraft.FKDraftStatus = tblDraftStatus.ID) 
    INNER JOIN tblMAlbumStatus ON tblMAlbums.FKMAlbumStatus = tblMAlbumStatus.ID) 
    INNER JOIN tblAlbumType ON tblMAlbums.FKAlbumType = tblAlbumType.ID) 
    INNER JOIN vw_CMP_Contacts ON vw_CMP_Matches.ContactNo = vw_CMP_Contacts.ContactNo
```

Next I have to join the draft requirements, by draft fk, to tbldraftreqs, and req type by fk req type.  I have the same for albums in an tblalbumreqs.

when i try to join those, I get no results, even though both have requirements.  The issue is, i'm directly joining drafts to albums, but then I need both requirements, and for them to line up together or alone, depending on if they both have the same requirement.

Make sense?

I'd love any pointers in solving this conundrum!

Comment: Show sample data, the query you tried that didn't work, what results you got, and what results you are trying to get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  There is only so much I can explain about a question. If the only comments are to complain that I didn't explain enough, I'll just keep researching on my own.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone else trying to do the same kind of joining.

```
SELECT mc.ID as mcid,  mc.FKContactDraft as Draftid, rq.ID, rq.txtRequirementType, Draft.FKRequirementType AS DraftReq, cont.FKRequirementType AS MCReq
from tblMAlbums mc
full join tblReqType rq on 1=1
left join tblContactDraftRequirements Draft on mc.FKContactDraft = Draft.FKContactDraft and rq.ID = Draft.FKRequirementType
left join tblMAlbumRequirements cont on mc.ID = cont.FKMC and rq.ID = cont.FKRequirementType
where mc.FKContactDraft is not null
```